# Flink : Unable to collect Task Metrics via JMX

Tags: apache-flink, jmx

I have been able to run JMX with Flink with the following configuration applied to the flink-conf.yaml file of all nodes in the cluster:

```
metrics.reporters: jmx
metrics.reporter.jmx.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.jmx.JMXReporter
metrics.reporter.jmx.port: 9020-9022

env.java.opts: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -        
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

When I run JConsole and listen on ports master-IP:9999/slave-IP:9020, I am able to see the system metrics like CPU, memory etc.

How can I access the task metrics and their respective graphs like bytesRead, latency etc. which are collected for each subtask and shown on the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to `mbeans tab` on jconsole and there you will see various dropdowns on RHS in the name of job and tasks. Let me know if you have any issues.